# 1-Сортировка идет по 1-му введённому значению ?2-Как обозначить переменную в списке по порядковому?

Tags: python

Не судите за глупый вопрос)
p.s за x я хотел обозначить позицию введённого числа.Заранее спасибо

```
b = []
print('Введите число 1')
b.append(input())
print('Введите число 2')
b.append(input())
print('Введите число 3')
b.append(input()) #сортировка затрагивает только первый введенный член,что был введен,например 12 стоит 1,а 2 уже вторым
b.sort()
for x in b: #я не знаю зачем я ввёл x , но в руководстве так написано
    x = x+1 #естественно,это действие не выполняется
    print(b)
```

Comment: а вы можете изложить свои мысли более связно, что именно вы хотите получить, в чем заключается задача?

Comment: Дана задача:
Напишите программу, которая в цикле ожидает последовательного ввода десяти(трёх) чисел по отдельности, добавляет их в список, а после этого сортирует данный список, и печатает его, умножив каждое число на 10.

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте так:

```
b = []

for _ in range(10):
    b.append(int(input("Введите число: ")))

b.sort()

for i in range(10):
    b[i] *= 10

print(b)
```

либо так:

```
b = []

for _ in range(10):
    b.append(int(input("Введите число: ")) * 10)

b.sort()
print(b)
```

Comment: простите,но в предложенных вариантах строка выводится примерно так

Comment: ['0', '1', '11', '12', '2', '2', '22', '23', '3', '432']

Comment: есть ли вариант вывести числа в порядковом построении?

Comment: числа также не умножаются(

Answer (score 3):

если я правильно понял задачу:

```
print(*map(lambda i: i * 10, sorted([int(input()) for _ in range(3)])))
```

последовательно получаем 3 числа в массив:

```
arr = [int(input()) for _ in range(3)]
```

сортируем массив

```
res = sorted(arr)
```

каждый член отсортированного массива умножаем на 10

```
output = map(lambda i: i * 10, res)
```

вот это решение чуть-чуть покороче:

```
print(*[10 * i for i in sorted([int(input()) for _ in range(3)])])
```

а это вообще короткое, хотя оно наверное не очень соответствует задаче

```
print(*sorted([10 * int(input()) for _ in range(3)]))
```

P.S.

постоянно забываю, что в таких случаях `[]` можно убрать:

```
print(*sorted(10 * int(input()) for _ in range(3)))
```

Comment: место `lambda` можно использовать `10 .__mul__`:)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать и так на основе Вашего кода.

```py
b = []
b.append(int(input('Введите число 1: ')))
b.append(int(input('Введите число 1: ')))
b.append(int(input('Введите число 1: ')))
b.sort()

print(b) # Выведем отсортированный список

for x in b:
    print(int(x)*10)
```

Готово )

Comment: сортировка будет проходить неверно, потому что вы сортируете строки, а нужно числа. вот так вот будет при вводе `1 10 2`: `['1', '10', '2']`

Comment: @n1tr0xs значит надо привести к int(input()). Пропустил сей момент спасибо

Answer (score 1):

"По-простецки":

```
N = 10
nums = []
for i in range(N):
    num = int(input(f'Введите число {i}'))
    nums.append(num)
nums.sort()
for num in nums:
    print(num*10)
```

Немного сокращаем, используя `list comprehension`:

```
N = 10
nums = [int(input(f'Введите число {i}:')) for i in range(N)]
nums.sort()
for num in nums:
    print(num*10)
```

В последнем примере можно вместо

```
nums = [int(input(f'Введите число {i}:')) for i in range(N)]
nums.sort()
```

написать так

```
nums = sorted([int(input(f'Введите число {i}:')) for i in range(N)])
```